# Quicksight unable to see glue catalog tables via Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight, aws-lake-formation

I have tried adding the Quicksight user to lake formation (still there, but I was not using LF intentionally; so not sure why I would have to do this), I have tried adding

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "glue:GetSchemaVersion",
                "glue:ListSchemaVersions",
                "kms:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

that inline policy to the quicksight service role (also tried * for actions).

Yes, I tried following - Securely analyze your data with AWS Lake Formation and Amazon QuickSight | AWS Big Data Blog

I can see the database and tables in the Athena interface and query them, but nothing shows up at all in QS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that Quicksight is unable to do cross-region access to Athena. You have to create a new glue database in the same region as quicksight if you want to use it with Athena.